# What kind of formula does MongoDB use to calculate distance in geospherical indexes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

In MongoDB is possible to create indexes than can be used to find documents `near` a given latitude and longitude both in the '2d' and '3d' space.

What kind of formula does MongoDB use to find the distance between two given latitude/longitude pairs?

A few that come to my mind are:

- Euclidean Distance
- Haversine Formula
- Vincenty Formula

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB (as at 2.2) only supports 2-d geospatial indexing, not 3-d.

Individual locations are encoded using the [geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) system on top of MongoDB B-tree indexes.

In MongoDB 1.8+ there is support for [Spherical correction](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-TheEarthisRoundbutMapsareFlat) for queries using decimal degrees.

There are [two main types](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.2/src/mongo/db/geo/2d.cpp#L1942) of distance calculations:

- Plain - [Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_Distance).  Source code reference is [db/geo/core.h:`distance()`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.2/src/mongo/db/geo/core.h#L434)
- Sphere - [n-Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-vector).  Source code reference is [db/geo/core.h: `spheredist_rad()`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.2/src/mongo/db/geo/core.h#L518).

Comment: Stennie, so when I query a '2d' indexed collection like this: `db.runCommand({geoNear:'my_collection', near:[my_lon, my_lat], spherical:true, maxDistance:my_dist_in_radiants})` mongodb will use the `n-Vector`, right? I'll take a look at the code but does that treat the earth as a perfect sphere?

Comment: @Stennie The distance returned by MongoDB's $near and javascript's Haversine formula is different. I want to use the same method in javascript that is used by MongoDB's spherical indexes. Could you help me on this?

Comment: @SandeepSharma This answer refers to the older `2d` index type in MongoDB, which was superceded by the `2dsphere` index type in MongoDB 2.4 and newer. Both types are still available as at MongoDB 3.4 and can be used by`$near`. The `2dsphere` index calculations are provide via an open source C++ library from Google called `s2` which uses the [Haversine formula](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/ac84a0d028eff2b8ca42817d998cb8b34563816c/src/third_party/s2/s2latlng.cc#L37). However, floating point calculation in JS will be less precise than C++ so I wouldn't expect identical results.

Comment: @SandeepSharma If you are seeing wildly different results, I suggest posting a new question with details on the JavaScript Haversine implementation you are using, some test data points, and the expected versus actual results.